# Java "test suite" for a new Collection implementation

Tags: java, unit-tests

I am currently writing a custom implementation of java.util.List and java.util.Map, which are "persistent" in a (relatively unknown) NoSQL DB. My worry is that those APIs are quite large, and that makes validating all possible API calls difficult. Searching for "unit-test for java collection" or similar only brings up how to test individual functions, like "remove()" ... What I'm looking for is a "full test suite" which would verify that my new collections behaves as they should, but idk how to formulate that, so I get usable results in a search engine.

Comment: In your case I would check, how to write good tests. Possibly you could use the testcases in the JDK collection sources.